# Python Keras NN, handling n_samples of float outputs

Tags: python, neural-network, classification, keras

I am using Keras with Theanos backend in Python.

I have 2117 samples and each sample has an individual target (on purpose) ie. 2117 outputs.

As opposed to categories, the targets are ratings eg. (16.4714494876, 17.4129353234, 17.4476570289) the entirety of the number is important.

I am having problems/don't know where to start.

1) When i run the NN it only outputs the targets as whole integers as opposed to the format of the actual values. eg. 16 instead of 16.xxxxxx

2) Presumably i will only be able to gauge the accuracy of predictions based on how close the output is to the target since there are so many targets, does this type of classification problem have a name that i can research?

3) In 3 research papers i have read that apply NN to my specific classification problem they list the output layer as only having 1 neuron but provide no further explanation, how could this be?

Here is my model.

```
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)

X = np.array(df[FEATURES].values)
Y = np.array(df["MTPS"].values)

# define baseline model
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=(len(FEATURES)), init='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(2117, init='normal', activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
#build model
estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=5, verbose=2)

#cross validation
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=seed)
estimator.fit(X_train, Y_train)

#print class predictions
print estimator.predict(X_test)
print Y_test
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you add the links of these 3 papers please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused. As you have said, the targets are ratings. It's definitely a regression problem to me, instead of a classification problem.

There's several problems in your code:

1. For regression problem, we usually use `linear` as activation function of the last layer (sometimes `relu`, even `sigmoid`).
2. And also we use `mse` as metric(sometimes `mae`, `msle`, etc). `categorical_crossentropy` is used for classification problem, and `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` is used for sparse input classification problem. [Ref](https://keras.io/objectives/)
3. `KerasClassifier` is used for classification problem, use `KerasRegressor` instead.
4. `metrics=['accuracy']` is used for classification problem, and it's meaningless in regression problem. [Ref](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4308)
5. Assuming `df` is a Pandas DataFrame, then `df.values` is naturally a `ndarrary`, there's no need to cast `np.array`.

Now answering your question:

1. As I've never used [wrappers for scikit-learn AP](https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/)I, I'm not very sure why you have integer output, my best guess is because of `KerasClassifier` and `.predict`(in scikit-learn APIs, `.predict` returns integer, basically the predicted class and `.predict_proba` returns float, indicating the probability of each class). Try to use `.predict_proba`, it would help. BTW, you should really use `KerasRegressor`.
2. As you have mentioned, there's so many classes to predict. In fact, it's a regression problem.
3. Could you please add the links of these 3 papers? Neural networks having only 1 neuron in output layer seem to be a regression NN to me. Regression NN usually uses `Dense(1, activation='linear')` as the output layer.

Here's my version of your code, it might work:

```
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)

X = df[FEATURES].values  # no need to cast np.array
Y = df["MTPS"].values

# define baseline model
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=(len(FEATURES)), init='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, init='normal', activation='linear'))  # one neuron, linear activation
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')  # mse loss
    return model
#build model
estimator = KerasRegressor(build_fn=baseline_model, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=5, verbose=2)  # KerasRegressor for regression problem

#cross validation
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=seed)
estimator.fit(X_train, Y_train)

#print class predictions
print estimator.predict(X_test)
print Y_test
```

### [References](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py#L174)

Comment: As you say, mistakenly i thought it was a classification problem as opposed to regression. I immediately understand the problem from your great answer. Thank you very much.